# Bulk processing make images square no cropping

Tags: image-processing, batch, aspect-ratio

I have hundreds of product photographs for my business. Now am assigning all of those to respective product codes on my ERP. But the erp accepts only square images (1:1) something like instagram or whatsapp profile. 
Could someone suggest a software for windows 7 which would do a bulk processing. All my images are of different dimension. I do not want the application to crop my images or change the aspect ratio, want it to just add white background color to fill in.

Basically I am looking for a SquareDroid app for Windows PC + bulk processing

I do not know scripting in Photoshop

TIA

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend Imagemagick. Something like this should work (untested)

```
FOR %a in (*.jpg) DO convert %a -resize 600x600 -background black -gravity center -extent 600x600 square_%a
```

---

Full steps to get this working when you're unfamiliar with scripting are as follows (written for Windows, but similar steps exists for Ubuntu and Mac OS):

1. [Download ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows).
2. Make a copy of the files you want to work on in a new folder (just in case something goes wrong).
3. Open the command prompt through the Windows start menu.
4. Navigate to the folder created in step 2 by typing `cd path/to/new/work/folder` into the command prompt.
5. List all the files in the folder with the command `dir`.
6. Try out the ImageMagick command on one file to see if the results are satisfactory. Adjust the `file_name0001.jpg` part to the filename of the image you want to try the script on (e.g. `DSC1001.jpg`) and write below line in the command prompt:
   `convert file_name0001.jpg -resize 600x600 -background black -gravity center -extent 600x600 square_output.jpg`

   - You can find the a description of the options in the [`convert` manual](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php). Here are direct links to the options used in the current command:[`-resize`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#resize), [`-background`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#background), [`-gravity`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity), [`-extent`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#extent)
7. Adjust the options as required. When you're satisfied with the end result you can run the command in a loop over all jpg files. In below command I use the same option values as in step 6 as an example.
   `FOR %a in (*.jpg) DO convert %a -resize 600x600 -background black -gravity center -extent 600x600 square_%a`

   - This command loops over all files in the folder of step 4 that end in `.jpg`.
   - Every file that ends in `.jpg` is put through the ImageMagick command of step 6.
   - After processing the ImageMagick command prepends `square_` to the filename and saves the processed file. The original file remains untouched.

Comment: Thank you for the response 
Is that scripting.? Am a lay man in terms of such commands :(  do I put those in ImageMagick. *embarrassed me